# ZeroDivisionError: float division` in python

Tags: python

```
querytimes = "SELECT video_id, COUNT(src_ip) FROM video GROUP BY video_id ORDER BY COUNT(src_ip) DESC"
cur.execute (querytimes)
dltimes = cur.fetchall()
for row in dltimes:

    videoid = str(row [0])
    downloadtimes = int(str(row [1]))
    x.append(rank)
    rank = rank + 1 
    y.append(downloadtimes)
    v.append(videoid)


counter = dict(zip(v, y))
for n in xrange(1, max(counter.itervalues()) + 1):
    perc = 100. / sum(1 for nb in counter.itervalues() if nb == n) / len(counter)
if perc:
   print '%.f%% videos have been downloaded %d times' % (perc, n)
```

This is my code. At first I read data from a database, then put videoid and downloadtimes into a dictionary, and do some calculation, but I got the following error:

`perc = 100. / sum(1 for nb in counter.itervalues() if nb == n) / len(counter)
ZeroDivisionError: float division`

Can anyone help a bit?

Comment: Is that last `for` loop right? the `if` part ought to be _inside_ the loop, otherwise it'll only execute once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked that your `counter` dictionary has at least one value that matches the `nb == n` condition? To me it seems like either your `sum` or your `len` return `0` as a result...

Check this out:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> counter = {'a': 1}
>>> 100. / sum(1 for nb in counter.itervalues() if nb == n) / len(counter) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
>>> counter = {'a': 3}
>>> 100. / sum(1 for nb in counter.itervalues() if nb == n) / len(counter) 
100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if `counter` is empty - in other words, if the value returned in `dltimes` doesn't have elements. I'd do something like this inside the `for` loop:

```
if counter:
    perc = 100. / sum(1 for nb in counter.itervalues() if nb == n) / len(counter)
else:
    perc = 0
```

Alternatively, it's possible that there are no values where `nb == n` it's True. in that case:

```
s = sum(1 for nb in counter.itervalues() if nb == n)
if counter and s:
    perc = 100. / s / len(counter)
else:
    perc = 0
```